# QGIS - Unknown projection of Excel-based data

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a database of coordinates of which the projection is unknown and I have to find out what it is. The coordinates are metric (so for example lat 388749, long 5014908); and they should refer to the north-west of Italy.

I have tried making some educated guesses and adding layers (from the csv file) assigning different CRS to them. These are the ones I've tried:

- EPSG 23032 (ED50 - UTM 32N)
- EPSG 32632 (WGS84 - UTM zone 32N)
- IGNF UTM32 (ED50 UTM fuseau 32)

Then I compared them to OpenStreetMap but in all these cases they end up in Somalia which is not quite at the antipodes of where they should be but close enough.

I'm realtively new to the program so I'm sure I'm missing something glaringly obvious.

Comment: Sounds like you switched X and Y coordinates when loading the excel into QGIS. Can you verify this?

Answer (score 1):

You have reversed the coordinates, they're not "lat", "long", they are X, Y (eastings, northings).

As to which of those UTM CRSs is, correct, I can't say.

[image]